# How to accurately use the rails diffy gem to compare another version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm trying to compare recipes and then display the versions in a show. The compare functionality and view works properly. I can see them both on the same page. However I want to use diffy to show just what's different between the two.

I'm using the partial "show" to output the differences. For sanity I want to build in this view diffy for the new "version". So below feel free to ignore: render "show", food: @version.

Right now in my compare(show) view I have the following:

```
  <div>
    <h1> Original recipe </h1>
    <%= render 'show', food: @original %>
  </div>
   <!-- Clone form  -->
  <div>
    <h1> Cloned recipe >> Version of the Original </h1>
    <%= render 'show', food: @version %>
    <div class='row mt'>
     <div class='col-sm-12'>
      <style><%= Diffy::CSS %></style>
       <div class='well diff'>
       <p>
        <strong>Name:</strong>
        <%= diff(food.recipe.name) %>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I honestly can't think of what to put in the line below to compare the two:

```
 <%= diff(food.recipe.name) %>
```

I've tried doing variations on @original and @version separated by commas and even built out a food helper to no avail.

My helper looks like:

```
   def diff(content1, content2)
    changes = Diffy::Diff.new(content1, content2,
                         include_plus_and_minus_in_html: true,
                         include_diff_info: true)
    changes.to_s.present? ? changes.to_s(:html).html_safe : 'No Changes'
  end
```

Thoughts on what I need to put in for diffy?

Comment: So I know I need two arguments and I've actually tested with other strings but no clue what to pass for version name and the origin name.

Answer (score 0):

Took awhile but:

```
 <%= diff(@version.recipe.name, @original.recipe.name) %>
```